# Why heroku can't run WebSocket server without HTTP server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

I have a WebSocket app on heroku. I tried uploading my WebSocket app without routing http server but it doesn't work. What does mean *server routing*? And why can't  heroku run a WebSocket server without an http server? 
And why does it takes express object 'server' as argument in SocketServer
Here's my code of Websocket server.

```js
const express = require('express');
const SocketServer = require('ws').Server;
const path = require('path');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const INDEX = path.join(__dirname, 'index.html');

const server = express()
  .use((req, res) => res.sendFile(INDEX) )
  .listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on ${ PORT }`));

const wss = new SocketServer({ server });
wss.on("connection",function(ws){
    ws.on("message",function(message){
        if(message==='exit'){
            ws.close();
        }else{
            wss.clients.forEach(function(client){
                client.send(message);    
            });
            console.log(message);
        }
    });
    ws.send("welcome..");
});
```

Comment: Websockels are set up over HTTP. you can't use them without.

Comment: Yeah but actually what happens in backend When express object is passed in SocketServer

Comment: And in localhost it works fine without routing http server.

Comment: @mehul Wasn't my answer helpful? If it was, please vote for it.

Comment: yeah I tried that day only but it says "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score"

Comment: And thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are too many questions in one. I hope my answers will address all of them.

First of all, the websocket protocol is an extension of http, it is not something different. Therefore, a websocket server is necessarily an http server, even though with extended capabilities.

Also, with socket.io, the websockets and http run on the same port. Therefore you have to open the port for http to have your websockets work.

Let's have a look at this line :

```
const wss = new SocketServer({ server });
```

It has a syntax error, it must be `new SocketServer(server)`. Also, about the variable name, I would recommend not to use `wss` for a websocket over http, since *wss* stands for *secure websockets* and is related to *websockets* like *http* to *https*.

About routing in heroku: in heroku, you have to define which port your application is using. This can be compared to the firewall on your local machine : if you want to access it from outside, you have to open the port. On heroku, technically it is different to a firewall, but in this point it is similar.